# Vectorizing t distribution in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I need to vectorize the non-centrality parameter in `R`'s `rt` t-distribution sampler. However, when I give:

```
rt(2, df = 1, ncp = c(1,2))
```

I get

```
Warning message:
In if (is.na(ncp)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Other functions such as `rbinom` or `rgamma` do not have a similar problem (i.e. `prob` argument in `rbinom` can be vectorized as can be the scale arguments of `rgamma`).

Is there a way to do this (without a loop)?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create a pseudo-vectorized function with `Vectorize`. For example, to vectorize `rt` with respect to the `ncp` argument, you can do:

```
vec.rt <- Vectorize(rt, "ncp")
```

The function can be used as in the code you tried earlier.

```
vec.rt(2, df=1, ncp=c(1,2))
#          [,1]     [,2]
# [1,] 3.314060 5.300499
# [2,] 2.423883 1.299248
```

Note that this doesn't give you a *real* vectorized function, and neither will `sapply` or `lapply`. All of these functions use loops internally, so you won't notice any performance increase in comparison with a cleanly written `for` construct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply`:

```
sapply( 1:3, function(x) rt(2, df = 1, ncp = x) )
#            [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,]  0.3881308 1.905535 1.781836
# [2,] -0.7950962 2.905824 1.633683
```

Each column in the resulting matrix corresponds to a different value of `ncp`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lapply`, `sapply`, or `vapply` with similar performance. `lapply` and `vapply` are a bit faster than `sapply` because `sapply` is a wrapper to `lapply` that attempts to make the results prettier/simpler.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  vapply(c(1,2, 3), function(x) rt(2, df = 1, ncp=x), numeric(2L)),
  sapply( 1:3, function(x) rt(2, df = 1, ncp = x) ),
  lapply( 1:3, function(x) rt(2, df = 1, ncp = x) ),
  vec.rt(2, df=1, ncp=1:3))

#Unit: microseconds
#  expr    min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#vapply 27.121  37.6095  51.61055  39.8825  42.4570 1226.199   100  a 
#sapply 51.438  58.1725  72.89417  60.9150  63.4850 1255.270   100  ab
#lapply 29.484  34.0670  59.78256  36.8160  39.0755 2326.401   100  ab
#vec.rt 95.511 101.6985 106.15785 105.0770 108.2700  189.312   100   b
```

Comment: Thanks for the comparison! One thing to keep in mind is that `sapply` is a wrapper for `lapply` and has an additional simplification step of converting the output to a matrix, which is what increases its run time.